# aws notifications for data transfer costs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, data-transfer

I am using an ec2 linux instance on aws, I am trying to stay inside the Free Usage Tier, but today I have noticed a charge for DataTransfer cost in Billing Management.

I don't know what the limits for DataTransfer are but I'm using aws for the host of a telegram bot

I would like to stay within the limits of the Free Usage Tier, is there a way to receive notifications just before exceeding the limit for data transfers or simply setting a limit not to be exceeded?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set up billing alerts, at any dollar amount you want, but keep in mind that if your service is getting slammed with requests, your account will still keep accumulating charges even after the alert is sent out - so depending on how long it takes you to respond to the alert (and turn off services for example), and how fast services are being consumed, you may still end up with an unexpected bill.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html

Comment: I'm trying to follow the link you sent but in the point "Choose Select metric. In the All metrics tab, choose Billing, Total Estimated Charge" The billing, total estimated charge option seems to be missing

Comment: Try entering 'billing' into the search box, there are 784 metrics to choose from, and they only show some by default

Comment: I don't know if there is any problem with my account but only 27 metrics are shown and if I search for billing this does not exist. I'm in the "create alarm" section, I inserted a screenshot in the post

Comment: With my 'root' account, and admin account I see almost 800 metrics - maybe your account doesn't have the proper access?

Comment: I am logging in as root user too, I can't understand why I don't have all those metrics

Comment: The Billing metrics are only available in the `us-east-1` console. (All billing data is managed in that region.) So, change your region and click on "Billing" in the left navigation pane.